# Who are all the characters / games represented in Steam's Humble Games Publisher Birthday Sale 2022 banner / picture?

Tags: game-identification

Who are all the characters in Steam's Humble Games Publisher Birthday Sale 2022 [banner](https://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/clans/6869120/f20e6c3ef14e81e05fdbb7f886c4446fa4ac5146.png) / picture?

[image: Steam's Humble Games Publisher Birthday Sale 2022 banner]

Which seem to reuse models from the banner of the [Humble Games 2021 Autumn Sale](https://www.humblegames.com/updates-article/2021-autumn-sale/).

It's really tall, but I'm most focused on the ones at the top. I can connect some of them [to the games on sale](https://store.steampowered.com/sale/BirthdaySale), being the ones featured in their game's store art but not all of them. Some of the ones I can identify are, from left to right:

1. Saffron of [One Step from Eden](https://youtu.be/LYJ2Rv_GOqg?t=12)
2. The [Ring of Pain](https://store.steampowered.com/app/998740/Ring_of_Pain/) bird
3. The robed being of [Wizard of Legend](https://store.steampowered.com/app/445980/Wizard_of_Legend/)
4. The flame holder of [Wildfire](https://store.steampowered.com/app/431940/Wildfire/).
5. Hat Kid of A Hat in Time.
6. Unhooded variant on [Archvale](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1296360/Archvale/)'s Sword wielder in the center of its art
7. The Unpacking teddy.
8. Carto.
9. [Flynn: Son of Crimson](https://store.steampowered.com/app/737520/Flynn_Son_of_Crimson/)
10. Otto of [Dodgeball Academia](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1422420/Dodgeball_Academia/)

20?. [The Wild at Heart](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1093290/The_Wild_at_Heart/).

21?. Peony of [Fae Tactics](https://store.steampowered.com/app/995980/Fae_Tactics/)

23?. Alma of [UNSIGHTED](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1062110/UNSIGHTED/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are also missing:

- The unnamed protagonist from **Forager**

[image]

- The prisoner from **Void Bastards**

[image]

- The Ruinhunter from **Aegis Defenders**

[image]

- The pilot from **Project Wingman**

[image]

- The squared character from **Popup Dungeon**

[image]

- The hooded guy from **Into the Pit**

[image]

- This white-haired guy with monocle from **Crying Suns**

[image]

- Ima (the yellow-dressed girl) from **Ikenfell**

[image]

- The Pyrolancer from **The Iron Oath**

[image]

- An [Oree](https://temtem.fandom.com/wiki/Oree) and its trainer from **Temtem**

[image]

- The guy staring at his watch should be a reference to **The Occupation**
  (in which time is a precious resource and your watch can be used to set alarms and timers)

[image]

- The guy with bowler should be the detective from **Floor 13: Deep State**
  (a dystopian thriller that takes place in London)

[image]

- The winking girl should be the "cartoonized" version of the girl in **Next Space Rebels** and also the source of the guy standing next to a rocket. They seem to be wearing the skull design shirt seen in the "JOIN THE NEXT SPACE REBELS" Key Features [GIF](https://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/1422430/extras/FMV.gif?t=1637781966) from the store page, which is also the same skull as in the store art.

[image]

- Irma (and that blacksmith guy) from **Moonscars**

[image]

And that's all, I hope!

Comment: Whoops, yep. Forager was obvious and I just forgot. But the others! Thanks! Good luck!

Comment: I figured out the sword-wielder in the center, after comparing the Autumn Sale art, which placed them beside Archvale, so you don't have to put that one down.

Comment: I think we're just missing the winking girl to the left of the pillar? Behind Hat Kid and the Archvale-r.

Comment: Ah. I see, yeah, they Rocket guy and winking girl seem to wearing the skull shirt seen in the "JOIN THE NEXT SPACE REBELS" Key Features GIF from the store page. https://store.steampowered.com/app/1422430/Next_Space_Rebels/
...
I gotta go maybe you edit it in? Or I'll do it on return.

Comment: So you're trying to find all of them? Even the ones at the bottom? Given that you haven't removed your "I'll add more once I figure them out." disclaimer. Good Luck!